# In C++, under the case `T object(other);`, is it direct initialization or copy initialization？

Tags: c++, initialization, copy-initialization, direct-initialization

Assume I have this code

`T object(other);`

It is direct initialization or copy initialization? Based on the rule of direct initialization :

> T object ( arg ); initialization with a nonempty parenthesized list of expressions

It is direct initialization.

But I saw someone said:

- It is **copy initialization** when `object` and `other` is **same type**.
- It is **direct initialization** when `object` and `other` is
  **different type**.

I don't know which is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All forms of `T object(other);` are direct initialization.  Direct initialization is defined in [[dcl.init.general]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#general-15) as:

> The initialization that occurs
>
> - **for an initializer that is a parenthesized expression-list or a braced-init-list,**
> - for a new-initializer ([expr.new]),
> - in a static_­cast expression ([expr.static.cast]),
> - in a functional notation type conversion ([expr.type.conv]), and
> - in the braced-init-list form of a condition
>
> is called direct-initialization.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Which covers `T object(other);`

Copy intialization is define in [[dcl.init.general]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#general-14) as:

> The initialization that occurs in the = form of a brace-or-equal-initializer or condition ([stmt.select]), as well as in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception ([except.throw]), handling an exception ([except.handle]), and aggregate member initialization other than by a designated-initializer-clause ([dcl.init.aggr]), is called copy-initialization.

`T object(other);` is not covered so it is not copy initialization.

Comment: Thank you! So the type of the `other` is doesn't matter, right?

Comment: @Kevineyeson Yes.

Comment: @Kevineyeson In a variable declaration, it has to have a `=` in it for it to be copy intialization